# What does asking how to write songs with millions of views have to do with the rest of the song in "אלוף העולם"?

Tags: song-lyrics, hebrew-language, hanan-ben-ari

The last verse in Hanan Ben Ari's "[אלוף העולם](https://mshironet.mako.co.il/artist?type=lyrics&lang=1&prfid=17593&wrkid=48648)" (Aluf HaOlam / Champion of the World) goes like this:

> אני אלוף העולם בלפצות
> להתנצל ולרצות
> לחטוא, להתנקות
> לחשוף, להתכסות
> תגידי, איך כותבים שירים עם אלף ציפיות
> מיליוני צפיות
>
> I'm the champion of the world in reconciling
> Apologizing and placating
> Sinning and cleaning up
> To reveal and cover up
> Say (feminine second person), how do you write songs with a thousand views
> Millions of views
> <sub>(translation by me)</sub>

What do these last couple lines have to do with the rest of the song (or the rest of the verse)? It doesn't seem to make any sense in context, so... why is it there?

Answer (score 3):

There's a small but crucial error in your translation. Correcting it will help us reconcile these lines with the whole song:

> תגידי, איך כותבים שירים עם אלף צ**י**פיות
> Say (feminine second person), how do you write songs with a thousand **expectations**

Throughout the song, Ben-Ari speaks about the challenges of relationships (with himself, his wife, children, fans). He sees himself as a champion of enduring these challenges. What matters is not whether he failed or succeeded, but kept going.

One such challenge is doing what everyone (including himself, as he declares in the first verse) thinks he's good at: Writing songs, not to say successful, viral songs.
But although he has doubts, he also has certainty that he can bare them and keep going.